An inequality including maximal function

Let $ f \in L^1\left(\mathbb{R}^n\right) $. Prove that for any $ \lambda > 0 $,
$$
\left|\left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : M f(x) > \lambda \right\}\right| \leq \frac{C}{\lambda} \int_{(|f| > \lambda / 2)} |f(x)| \, dx
$$
where the constant $C$ is independent of $\lambda$ and $f$.

I have thought of two ways to try to solve this problem but neither has been successful.
First, I tried to use weak-(1,1)-inequality. Trying to find a function $g$ such that $$
\left|\left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : M f(x) > \lambda \right\}\right| \leq|\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : Mg(x) > \lambda\}| \leq \frac{C}{\lambda} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |g(x)| \, dx=\frac{C}{\lambda} \int_{(|f| > \lambda / 2)} |f(x)| \, dx$$
And a (wrong) example is $g(x) = f(x) \chi_{\{|f(x)| > \lambda/2\}}$. It cannot solve this problem.
Second, I tried to use Vitali Covering Lemma. We have $$\left|\left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : M f(x) > \lambda \right\}\right|\subset \bigcup_{i} B(x_i, 5r_i)$$
Then $$\left|\left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : M f(x) > \lambda \right\}\right|\leq\frac{5^n}{\lambda} \sum_i \int_{B(x_i, r_i)} |f(y)| \, dy$$
But I cannot relate it to $\{|f| > \lambda / 2\}$.

How can I solve this? Or both of the two ways are wrong? Or someone can find the source of this problem?


I tried to use weak-(1,1)-inequality. Trying to find a function $g$ such that [...] And a (wrong) example is $g(x) = f(x) \chi_{\{|f(x)| > \lambda/2\}}$. It cannot solve this problem.

Why do you think that this $g$ doesn't work ? In fact this $g$ does work, the trick is to write $f\equiv f \chi_{\{|f(x)| > \lambda/2\}} + f \chi_{\{|f(x)| \le \lambda/2\}}$, which I will rewrite $f\equiv f_> + f_\le$. Now from the definition of $M$ and the triangle inequality it is easy to see that
$$Mf = M(f_> + f_\le)\le Mf_>+Mf_\le, \tag1$$
and $$Mf_\le(x) \le \|f_\le\|_\infty = \frac\lambda2. \tag2$$
Hence by combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ we have the inclusion
$$\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : M f(x) > \lambda \} \subseteq \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : M f_>(x) > \lambda/2 \} $$
And your desired inequality follows by applying the weak inequality to $f_>$.
